# Workplace Message API issues with time range

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I'm trying to use Workplace API to retrieve messages of users by this API

`GET graph.facebook.com/{member-id}/conversations?fields=messages{message,attachments,from}`

I successfully got the sample data. However, I got problem with using Since and Until parameters with that API when saw that they may not work together cause the `create_time` of message is not filterd by Since parameter. Moreover, I can't retrieve all messages of any users each request.

Please help to use the time range to limit response of users' messages by time range.
Document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/member#userinbox

Thank you!

I tried to call Workplace API and I expect to use parameters to limit the response